# How to account for shifting seasonality arising due to differences between gregorian and Islamic calendars?

Tags: time-series, seasonality, decomposition, multiple-seasonalities

I am trying to predict time series through decomposition, my time series is as follows,
[image]

As islamic calendars lag the gregorian calendar by 10 days after each year, so my seasonality is also changing, when I try to decompose time series through normal decomposition, constant seasonality pattern comes, although this is contrary to what should have been.

[image]

For example in this case seasonality is always constant, What should be the way of solving this problem.

The things that i have come across and after thinking myself is:
1)use decomposition on each year(or Two years), separately, i am confused that how would i include future with this kind of task, as i donot know future.
2) Instead of dealing separately Seasonaity and residues, use predictors to catch this sifting seasonality.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what the TBATS method was designed to handle. See https://robjhyndman.com/publications/complex-seasonality/ for the paper. The method is implemented in the `tbats()` function from the `forecast` package in R.

Comment: Thank you Rob Hyndman, I have implemented tbats on my data set and it is indeed giving acceptable results 
[link](https://www.linkpicture.com/q/Capture_160.png)

Comment: I want to ask that how would i deal with outliers in time series using tbat, i have searched documentation but i could not find any clue, In STL we could have used robust fitting to avoid outliers, is their a way in TBAT to have such capability. Due to corona time series had changed in the lockdown period, is their a way to account for correction?
eg such anomalies.
[link]https://www.linkpicture.com/q/Capture_174.png

Comment: You could pre-clean your data to replace outliers with estimates. The tsclean() function can help with that.